# Deserializing and getting the value from completely dynamic JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I'm scraping the internet, therefore, the JSON I'm analyzing will be completely different on each webpage. In a nutshell, though, I'm looking to find the author's name.

I'm currently using:

```
           dynamic results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(value);
           string Author = results.Author;
```

The problem is, two pages are never the same.

This is an example of two different web pages, with schema which I will find and deserialize & find the author's name.

Example 1:

```
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "BookSeries",
    "author": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "givenName": "Douglas",
        "familyName": "Adams",
        "additionalName": "Noel",
        "birthDate": "1952-03-11",
        "birthPlace": {
            "@type": "Place",
            "address": "Cambridge, Cambridgeshire, England"
        }
    }
}
```

Example 2:

```
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "name": "Lecture 12: Graphs, networks, incidence matrices",
    "author": "James Beckett",
    "description": "These video lectures of Professor Gilbert Strang teaching 18.06 were recorded in Fall 1999 and do not correspond precisely to the current  edition of the textbook.",
    "publisher": {
        "@type": "CollegeOrUniversity",
        "name": "MIT OpenCourseWare"
    },
    "license": "http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/us/deed.en_US"
}
```

Is there a way of truly being dynamic, and finding said values within a JSON string, no matter how they're formatted? With static JSON it's very simple, however, like this - I have absolutely no clue because you can't turn the JSON into C# classes, because they'll always be different.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: A recursive methods that checks, e.g., `var token = JToken.Parse(json);
var tAuthors = token.Where(t => t.ToString().IndexOf("author", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);`. But, how are you *presenting* the results? Or make use of them? Are you querying an *indefinite* number of sources? Sure, you can extract all properties of JTokens that match, but then?

Comment: This does work, however, it falls over if it returns this example value: `{"author": [
  {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "Harry Howard"
  },
  {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "Chris Jewers"
  }
]}` As opposed to returning the value of the author, it returns the JSON. As for your question, it's more curiosity as opposed to actually having something to use from it.

Comment: Nope, in both cases (which is actually the same case), `tAuthors[0]` contains the `authors` token value. You probably inspected the `token` variable. Add `.ToList()` to the `Where()` clause results to see it better.

Comment: Anyway, you could the same thing using dynamic, e.g., `var author = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json).author.ToString();`, unless the (A-a)uthor is contained in a nested object, in this case you need a recursive method, as mentioned. Same considerations for the usability.

Comment: How would you propose getting the value of `"name":`? I'm currently using                         `foreach (var persons in tAuthors){
                            Console.WriteLine(persons);
                        }` which just gives me back pure JSON.

Comment: `dynamic` is not helping here.  Instead, deserialize explicitly to `JObject` (which is what you are getting anyway) and do `results.SelectTokens("..author")` to get the values of all properties named `"author"`.  See e.g. [How do I get a deeply-nested property from JSON string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36324494/3744182)  Or you could use `JContainer.Descendants()`  to search for properties named `"author"`, see e.g. [Search for a nested value inside of a JSON.net object in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40666941/3744182).

Comment: Of course since the possible `"author"` values have different schemas, it's not clear how you will handle them once you have them.